# App engine TaskQueue task impacting user facing handlers performance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

My queue task uses `urlfetch` to get some data from an external API and saves it to ndb Datastore entities.

This takes about 15 seconds total.

Somehow, when the task runs, all other handlers (simple json response handlers) become slower. (slower means +500ms)

**What could be causing this?**

Isn't the idea of background tasks that is doesn't affect the user facing requests.

I stumbled upon [this blogpost](http://bjk5.com/post/7796556212/fast-and-slow-queues-on-app-engine), but my task takes longer than 1 second to complete. I don't see how that's going to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your tasks are executed by the same instances that serve user requests. Background or not, they share the same CPU, memory and bandwidth. It's a good idea to run these tasks on a different module, which means a different instance. You can do it by specifying a target for your task queue.

Note that typically an automatic App Engine scheduler will spin a new instance when responses from your current instances slow down. However, a slowdown in your case is caused not by the growing volume of standard requests, but an unusual request which takes much longer. This prevents automatic scheduler from reacting to the increased latencies. You can switch to manual or basic scheduling, which give you more control over capacity (total number of instances) and rules for spinning new instances, but creating a different module for background tasks is a better solution.